# Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/carphoto.php on line 47

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a jpeg image on a website i am working on but keep receiving the following error:

```
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/carphoto.php on line 47
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for Array in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/carphoto.php on line 48
Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/carphoto.php on line 48
Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/speedycm/public_html/speedyautos/carphoto.php on line 49
```

the file carphoto.php has the following code on lines 47-49

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES["pics"]["tmp_name"], 'rb'); 
$contents = fread($fp, filesize($_FILES["pics"]["tmp_name"]));  
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your first warning? What is $_FILES['pics']['tmp_name']? try var_dumping it.

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually because you're using multiple file uploads in your html form and using an array to group them together. Like:

```
<input type="file" name="pics[]"> ...
```

So php groups these tmp_files into an array accordingly.

You'll probably want to reference them individually

```
foreach($_FILES["pics"]["tmp_name"] as $file) {
      ....
}
```